# How to create multiple listeners in ActiveMQ using spring JMS

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a use case where I want to create multiple listeners(6) in an application. I want to subscribe to multiple destinations(6 topics). **All the subscription are durable**. I am using separate default message listener container(DMLC) for each listener and using different client id but I am confused about how connection factory should be used.

Should I use single ActiveMQ pooled connection factory with maxConnection specified to 6. OR should I use different pooled connection factory for each listener ?
  Is there any harm is using pooledConnectionFactory with maxConnection for durable subscriber?

**Source code:**
Connection Factory:

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
destroy-method="stop">
<property name="connectionFactory">
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL">
<value>${jms.broker.url}</value>
</property>
</bean>
</property>
<property name="maxConnections" value="6" />
```

**and my listener is using it as:** (I have 6 similar listeners similar to this using different destinations and client ID)

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"

      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
      <property name="destination" ref="topic_pnlCompleteTopic" />
      <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="FAGCompletion" />
      <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
      <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="${jms.fagsListener.durable}" />
      <property name="clientId" value="${jms.fagsListener.clientId}" />
      <property name="messageListener" ref="pnlMessageListener" />
      <property name="messageSelector" value="JMSType = 'FAG Completion'" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds all fine to me as long as you're not using this connection factory for something else. There is no reason to limit the number of connections to 6, you can put a higher number if you want and it will be only used if necessary. `ConnectionFactory` is typically the thing that you share for your whole app. See it as a kind of `DataSource` for JMS access

Comment: As you said "you're not using this connection factory for something else".. If I use this in JMStemplate to create producer and in DMLC to create consumers (as shown above). Will it cause problem if I use same connection factory for both JMStemplate and DMLC ?

Comment: As you said "no reason to limit the number of connections to 6" When i try with less than 6 connections, it is giving me below error because it is a durable subscriber and each subscriber should have different client id for a connection.                                                       **org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful 875 WARN] - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'topic://.seedTCAStatusPush' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Setting clientID on a used Connection is not allowed **

Answer (score 1):

You listeners will typically only use one session each, since you are using topics. There is no reason to specify a limit on your pool, or to use multiple pools. You typically use one pooled connection factory for your application unless you see a real reason to limit or split it up into different pools.

Comment: I have to put this limit on connections. If I use less than 6 connections, I get this error because of durable subscribers " **org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#refreshConnect‌​ionUntilSuccessful 875 WARN] - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'topic://.seedTCAStatusPush' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Setting clientID on a used Connection is not allowed **"

Comment: Can you please respond ?

Comment: I did not say you should use *less* than 6. I just said there is no reason for a limit for your listeners.

Comment: Thanks Petter. So even if I use same connection factory for producers(using JMStemplate) and consumers(using DMLC) by specifying maxConnection to required value. It should be fine?

Comment: And one more question: If I use more than one pooledconnectionFactory in my application (let's say 2 consumers are using one and other 3 consumers are using another pooled connection factory), Will it cause any trouble ?

Comment: No. the max value is to make sure your app does not go berserk and flood the JMS server with connections.

Comment: and even if I use same connection factory for producers(using JMStemplate) and consumers(using DMLC) by specifying maxConnection to required value. It should be fine?

Comment: Can you please respond ?

Comment: Can you please pay attention? Only you can guess what amount of concurrent producers you will have running. But yes, you can share pools. A suggestion is to load test your setup with above expected load and monitor usage/performance to se that it fits your need.